# How to further filter variable within a list that has multiple data.frame

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frame and want to filter variables base one a variable list.

The codes I used is

```
datalist1<-map(datalist, function(.x) .x <-.x %>% select(any_of(Valst$Var.name)))
```

If my datalist has 5 data.frame: `data1, data2, data3, data4, data5`.

Q1: If I only want to use Valst$Var.name to filter out data2, data3, data4, what should I do?
Q2: what if I want to keep extra variable `var6` in `data3`, what should I do?

Any guidance on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Q1: If I only want to use Valst$Var.name to filter out data2, data3, data4, what should I do?

Only pass those list items to `map`:

```
datalist1[2:4] <- map(
  datalist[2:4], 
  function(.x) .x <-.x %>% 
    select(any_of(Valst$Var.name))
)
```

> Q2: what if I want to keep extra variable `var6` in `data3`, what should I do?

This is harder to answer generally. Maybe you make a list of columns to keep, and then use `map2` to iterate over both the column list and the pertinent items from the data frame list.

```
cols_to_keep = rep(list(Vaslt$Var.name), 3)
cols_to_keep[[2]] = c(cols_to_keep[[2]], "var6")
map2(
  datalist[2:4],
  cols_to_keep,
  function(.x, .y) .x <-.x %>% select(any_of(.y))
)
```

But there are a lot of ways to handle special cases, and which one makes sense will depend a lot on how you detect them (manual? `if()` based on data? based on other data?) and how different the handling is.

Comment: For Q1, What if I have 100 data, can I just remove the unwanted data  by its' name?

Comment: The answer to Q2 looks nice. Can we modify it so I can keep all variables in data1 in the similar way?

Comment: Yeah, go for it! I don't think I can do it without sample data, but give it a go, and if you get stuck ask a new question!